# How to assign an image to a button?

Tags: android, image, button

I want to assign an image to one of the buttons in my activity?

How can i achieve that??
And for that where shall I place image.jpeg or any other image file?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).
Put your image in resources, and use it like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

its pretty old question but seems like you didn't get best solution on this post because still haven't accepted any answer.

```
So if we need a "button with Image" then we have two options
```

1. either we can go for Image Button as 'Orsol' mentioned in his answer
2. or simply you can Add Normal Button and then set Image to Background using Properties

code will be like this

```
<Button 
android:background="@drawable/square_1_up" 
android:layout_height="62dp" 
android:layout_width="65dp" 
android:id="@+id/button1">
</Button>
```

for this we need to put button image in Drawable folder named "square_1_up.png"

output Button will be like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Save these file under res/drawable/button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

### Suppose your main layout file main.xml which is under res/layout/main.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
 <ImageButton
 android:src="@drawable/button.xml"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_heght="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/button1"  
 />
</LinearLayout>
```